# f2py-f90wrap error `undefined symbol: __test_mod_MOD_p`

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am trying to wrap some Fortran using f90wrap, which is built on f2py. (I can use f2py, but I want to extend some code to use derived types).

Here is a simple `.f90` test code that I have tried to wrap:

```
module test_mod

   integer::p

end module
```

I have compiled and wrapped with the following commands:

```
gfortran -fPIC -c test.f90

f90wrap -m test test.f90

f2py-f90wrap -c -m _test f90wrap_*.f90
```

When I run:

```
python test.py
```

on this `test.py` file which is produced:

```
import _test
import f90wrap.runtime
import logging

class Test_Mod(f90wrap.runtime.FortranModule):
    """
    Module test_mod


    Defined at test.f90 lines 1-3

    """
    @property
    def p(self):
        """
        Element p ftype=integer pytype=int


        Defined at test.f90 line 3

        """
        return _test.f90wrap_test_mod__get__p()

    @p.setter
    def p(self, p):
        _test.f90wrap_test_mod__set__p(p)

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ['<test_mod>{\n']
        ret.append('    p : ')
        ret.append(repr(self.p))
        ret.append('}')
        return ''.join(ret)

    _dt_array_initialisers = []


test_mod = Test_Mod()
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _test
ImportError: _test.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __test_mod_MOD_p
```

Having dug through the f90-wrap repo and looked at the makefile for some of the tests in there I see the same process on the following .f90 file doesn't produce the same issue:

```
module testextends_mod


PUBLIC

    ! -----------------------------------------------
    type Superclass
        ! IN: Ask subroutine to stop in the middle.
        integer :: stop_at = -1     ! -1 --> don't stop
    end type Superclass

    type, extends(Superclass) :: Subclass1
        integer :: nl
    end type

    type, extends(Superclass) :: Subclass2
        integer :: nl
    end type

end module
```

Can anyone see what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
  gfortran -c -O3 -fPIC test.f90
  f90wrap -v -m test test.f90
  f2py-f90wrap -c -m _test f90wrap_test.f90 test.o
```