# How can I define a setup.py for a package which needs f90wrap to wrap Fortran sources?

Tags: python, fortran, setup.py, f2py

I am trying to figure out how to use Fortran sources in a Python package. I have previously had success using f2py and Numpy's distutils. This allows one to create a `setup.py` which automatically builds the Fortran code, creates `.pyd` files, and puts everything in place in the site-packges folder. However, now I need to use f90wrap, because I am using derived types in my Fortran code, which is not supported directly by f2py.

When simply following the process described on the f90wrap Github README to build Python bindings I got an undefined symbol error. This problem was described by: [f2py-f90wrap error `undefined symbol: __test_mod_MOD_p`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460221/f2py-f90wrap-error-undefined-symbol-test-mod-mod-p/48473763#48473763). There, a solution for this problem is given which involves first creating `.o` files from the Fortran source using the Fotran compiler directly, and then including these `.o` files when calling the f2py command:

> ```
> gfortran -c -O3 -fPIC test.f90
> f90wrap -v -m test test.f90
> f2py-f90wrap -c -m _test f90wrap_test.f90 test.o
> ```
>
> (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473763/10596345)

I have indeed been able to successfully create Python bindings using this solution (except for the fact that I use the `f2py` command directly instead of the wrapped `f2py-f90wrap` for the third step), but how would I properly wrap all of this in a working `setup.py` script that does this automatically and installs the package in the right place?

For completeness, here is the source of the simple `test.f90` file I am trying to turn into a Python package:

```
module test
    type, public :: Object
        real :: number
    end type Object
contains
    subroutine test(obj)
        type(Object), intent(in) :: obj
        write(*, *) obj%number
    end subroutine test
end module test
```

I would like to be able to use the `test` subroutine defined in this file, which takes the derived type `Object` as input, as a function in Python.